# From native c++ to .NET c++

Tags: c++, wrapper, managed-c++

I have a project in native c++ , it is an crystal reports viewer . The project it is complex containig support for working with files ( an imported project ) .I have to rewrite this code in c++.NET ,more specifically in managed c++ because i am using vs2003 service pack 1 .

I have written the crystal viewer in managed c++ and now i have to combine my new viewer with the working with files project . Rewriting the working with files project it not fiable solution .

What would be an proper approach ?

Thanks.
Bye.

Comment: Choose C# over managed C++ if you have the choice.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that option .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an unmanaged C++ project in a managed C++ project just fine. Just add a reference to the unmanaged .lib or DLL and add #include directives for the headers.